# Creating a file/folder in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app

first of all I really hope I'm not asking already answered question, I did my research on stack overflow and beyond and so far didn't find answer to my question.

I finally accomplished that my Universal windows (10) app makes a project folder for user, inside LocalState folder, but its fine as long as it stays there. Now, I'm trying to generate some simple text file and save in "Project" folder, example path: LocalState\Project1\example.txt.

I tried with following code:

```
StorageFolder mapa_projekta = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile sampleFile = await mapa_projekta.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt");
```

But it only saves to LocalState directory, maybe there is simple solution of adding path to the sub folder, but so far I didn't succeed in that.

Sorry for my poor english and thanks for all your time

Wish you all nice day

Comment: You would need to create an instance of StorageFolder using the path you want to save into instead of ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, we can make the project folder:

```
StorageFolder rootFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var projectFolderName = "Project1";
StorageFolder projectFolder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync(projectFolderName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceIfExisting);
```

Then, you can create your file within your subfolder:

```
StorageFile sampleFile = await projectFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't tell how stupid I feel now, it's just that I'm so used to form or wpf applications and really have to adapt a bit on UWP. Thanks again