# UWP: Unable to create folders or files

Tags: uwp

I have been following these pages to try to create a folder and a file in the local application directory of my UWP project:

[Creating a file/folder in UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389489/creating-a-file-folder-in-uwp?rq=1)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files

So far, no success. I followed the code example in the first link but no folder is created anywhere in my project.

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFolder projectFolder = await storageFolder.CreateFolderAsync("HereIsATestFolder", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = await projectFolder.CreateFileAsync("OutputCharacterizationTable.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

I also tried to load up the code example in the second link to create a file and write to it, but again nothing.

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

I'm also not receiving any errors or exceptions from running the app, so I'm stuck, as far as debug goes. Is there anything else I could be missing? I'm running VS2017.

Comment: If there are no exceptions - are you certain you are looking at the right location? Put a breakpoint and check out `sampleFile.Path` to make sure.

Comment: That was exactly it! It dumped my file deep in users/AppData/Local/...

I was expecting it to put the files somewhere in my project directory. Can that be done? I scanned through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions but couldn't find anything that look like that. I know that the base area of the project directory is protected against Writes.

Comment: Well, `LocalFolder` refers to the application deployment location. Accessing other locations requires either working with manifest declarations or asking user for the permission at the runtime, as in [Open files and folders with a picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers). You are right that folders like your source code aren't accessible to all UWP applications by default, but you can ask the user to pick that folder to grant access and optionally keep that permission in the `FutureAccessList`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information! If you care to, you could reframe your answer into a another post on this thread and I can mark it up :)